# Считывание строки в цикле

Tags: c, строки, циклы

Читая в цикле строки из консоли натыкаюсь на неведомый дроп программы. Никаких ошибок нет, просто предложение прибить процесс. С помощью `gcc(mingw)` компилится без каких-либо ошибок. Код без цикла работает по моему начальному замыслу.

После первого ввода строки цикл не доходит до конца итерации, а предлагает сразу ввести следующую строку. Сразу после второго ввода прога падает.

Я не знаю где моя ошибка, помогите, пожалуйста. Я говорю про цикл for, а не while

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef char *string;

int MY_strlen(string str);

int main(){

    int i, length, median;
    string input;

    for(i=0; i<10; i++){
        input = "";
        scanf("%s", input);
        printf("%s\n", input);
        length = MY_strlen(input);
        if(length%2 == 0)
            printf("%d\n", (input[length/2-1]-'0')*10+(input[length/2]-'0'));
        else
            printf("%d\n", input[length/2]-'0');
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

int MY_strlen(string str){
    int i=0;
    while(str[++i] != '\0')
        ;
    return i;
}
```

Comment: О боже!

    #include <string.h>
    typedef char *string;

Comment: охренеть)) Это анекдот какой-то)))

Comment: @moron `scanf("%s", input);` не читает строку файла. Из man scanf:

    s      Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters; the next pointer must be a pointer to character array  that
              is long enough to hold the input sequence and the terminating null byte ('\0'), which is added automatically.
              The input string stops at white space or at the maximum field width, whichever occurs first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

у вас переменная **input**, в которую нужно прочитать строку является указателем в никуда.
вместо всяких typedef-ов объявите **input** как ***char input[128]***, например.

Comment: Угу, попытка чтения (то есть, изменения) по адресу константной строки `""` — классический пример undefined behaviour.